# Sound settings vanished after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, sound, xfce, ubuntu-studio

After upgrade to 18.04 LTS the sound settings vanished from the panel:

[image: This is how the panel looks like]

They vanished even from the system settings:

[image: and here the system settings]

What to reinstall?

BTW: I had to add the Wi-Fi item to the panel after the upgrade too. I tried this with the sound settings but there is nothing available.

Comment: Hi Franta S.
I'd like to help you. Therefore I want to know a liitle bit more. Can you please add a Screenshot of the panel and the system settings?

Comment: Hi Boba Fit, thanks for your comment. I made the screenshots but how to add them here?

Comment: You have to edit your question. (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1096810/edit)

Comment: Ah you are using Ubuntu Studio. I recommend you to add the tags: ubunut studio, and  xfce. I'm sory I don't know much about this desktop enviroment. Perhaps you can use "pavucontrol" - thats a nice tool i use in Gnome